# Are the speed of sound and water ripples' speed the same?

Tags: waves, acoustics, water, speed

When a droplet of water hits the surface of a lake it produces ripples that travel outward. My conception is that it travels at the speed of sound in water (since sound are nothing less that perturbations on the medium).

But ripples travel much slower than that. What's happening? Is my conception of propagation of ripples wrong?

Perhaps that discrepancy is related to the difference between *[group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity)* and [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity)?

Answer (score 14):

The restoring force for waves on the surface of water is *gravity*, is why such waves are called "gravity waves"  (not *gravitational* waves!). Gravity waves on deep water have
$$
\omega_{\rm gravity}(k)= \sqrt{{gk}},
$$
which is independent of the density of the water.

The restoring force for sound waves in water is the water's elastic properties and
$$
\omega_{\rm sound}= \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{\rho}}k
$$
where $\kappa$ is the bulk modulus and $\rho$ is the density. The waves therefore have completely different origins and properties.

Comment: Great answer. I have a question though: wouldn't the restoring force on the surface wave be the water cohesion?

Comment: @ Pedro Pinho.  There is small effect due to surface tension, but it is only more imortant than gravity (i.e the water's weight wanting to make the water flat)   when the wavelength is a few millimeters or less. The Wikipedia article on *capillary waves* has details.

Comment: Interesting. What is $k$ in your first equation?

Comment: It is the  wavenumber: $k=2\pi/\lambda$. And $\omega$ is the angular frequency $\omega=2\pi f$.

Comment: Aren't there some non-linear effects (on deep water)? What is the "range" of the model?

Comment: What (constant) speed do the waves actually propagate at?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Your question rests on a false premise because gravity waves are [dispersive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation).